# Protect etc/hosts file on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web, host

I'd like to prevent my `etc/hosts` file from being edited.

Specifically, I'd like to make it so that it's not possible for users to edit the hosts file.

Here are some of the things I've tried:

1- I tried to make user group without permission to edit the file and then put myself in that user group

It didn't work because I don't have admin access on the Mac

2- I tried to use the instructions here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282339/protect-hosts-file

It's easy to edit because the user just needs this code `sudo chflags noschg /etc/hosts`

Any recs?

Comment: You're asking admin to make a boulder so heavy that it can't lift it, or a heat burrito so hot that it can't eat it.  Admin is omnipotent, it can do anything, including things that it cannot.  All you can do is not give users admin rights.

Comment: I'm not admin on the machine. I'd like it so that my user can't 'lift the boulder'

Comment: The point is that if the users can `sudo` to use admin rights then they have admin rights, and can eat that burrito and lift that boulder.

Answer (score 3):

Make all users non-admin who aren't supposed to be editing system files.

Another solution is to edit `/etc/sudoers` and change %admin entry to exclude certain commands being run from sudo (I haven't tested it):
`%admin ALL = (ALL) ALL, !chflags`

This is not foolproof, since there is always a way to circumvent sudo if you are an admin. That's why the first solution is better.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I'm not admin on the machine - though I can make requests to the administrator.